# Linux expect newline

Tags: docker, expect

I have a custom package I want to install automatically in my docker using expect.

The first thing the package asks me to do is press Enter to continue, then it prints another 2 empty lines then it waits for an input.

[image]

My expect script :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

spawn ./install

expect "\n"
send -- "\n"
```

But as you can see in the image, it just runs the installer and exits.

I tried removing the `expect "\n"` so only `send -- "\n"` will execute but now even the install message doesn't appear (tried with `set timeout 1000` before send and it also didn't work)

Any ideas?

P.S : This is a link to the package if anyone wants to have a go at it:

https://www.bayometric.com/downloads/digital-persona/DP_UareU_Linux223_20140429.2.zip

(the installer is inside DP-UareU-RTE-2.2.3-1.20140429_1533.tar.gz)

Comment: Are you sure this is a Docker related issue? Doesn't seem to me like one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expect "\n"` match a linefeed exactly, I think this is not what your program is sending.

To wait for a Shell prompt you can use `expect "%"` or `expect "*"` to match anything.

If you need to make sure you're dealing with the right prompt you may be able to use something like `expect "*Linux Installation*"`.

Also don't send `\n` but `\r` for the *enter* key :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ./install

expect "*Linux Installation*"
send "\r"

expect eof
```

Note that the default flag is `-gl` for [glob pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) but you can also use the `-re` flag for [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matching.

Comment: It initially didn't work for me so you should update your answer with my tweaks: 1) Remove #!/bin/sh. 2) Add expect after the send line so the script wont exit too quickly

Comment: Yeah sorry it was not intended to be used as is. I use `/bin/sh` shebang, but adapt it to your needs, depending on your use it may not be useful. Anyway I have updated my answer to remove it.

Comment: You should also add `set timeout -1` in case the install takes longer than (the default) 10 seconds.